# What is the representation of scanf in c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, cin, scanf

---

I am the beginner in C++ and I want to know the equivalent representation of 
     scanf("%c",&c)
in C++, anyone please tell me how i can write this statement `enter code here`in c++??

Comment: See this [`cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) while I'm voting to close.

Comment: Please have a look [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/). Perhaps you need to visit [How to ask on Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Why am I downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react) ?

Comment: btw, scanf will work in c++ too...

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent representation of `scanf("%c", &c)` in C++ is `scanf("%c", &c)`. C++ is quite nicely compatible with most of C - you can `malloc`, `scanf`, `printf` etc.

However, if you want to follow the real spirit of C++, you should do it in the object-oriented way:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

The main downside of this solution is, that if you *really* want to know what is behind that `std::cin >> c`, you have to learn *automatic class allocation*, *chained calls* and *operator overloading*.

Anyway, grabbing a good book on C++ or nicely written tutorial, which covers basics of this language seems to be a good thing to do in your situation. You won't learn much by asking questions about such basics on the SO.

There are more specifics to be considered:

> `std::cin>>c;` is not equivalent to `scanf("%c", &c);`. `operator>>` will skip leading spaces, but `scanf("%c"...` will not, so If the user were to enter `s`, the scanf call would read `' '` into `c`, but the `>>` would read `'s'` into `c`. You can use the `noskipws` manipulator to change this, so: `std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c;` would be (at least closer to) equivalent to the `scanf` call.
>   (thanks **[Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin)** for the comment)

Comment: `std::cin>>c;` is *not* equivalent to `scanf("%c", &c);`. `operator>>` will skip leading spaces, but `scanf("%c"...` will not, so If the user were to enter ` s`, the `scanf` call would read ' ' into `c`, but the `>>` would read "s" into `c`. You can use the `noskipws` manipulator to change this, so: `std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c;` would be (at least closer to) equivalent to the `scanf` call.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Are you *really* sure, that we should dig into such specifics in case of answering people, who either have none or minimum knowledge about C++? I would start from explaining why batch-script-style `cin >> c` works at all in C++ and then possibly go into specifics of this operator overload.

Comment: @JerryCoffin BTW, I can bet, that the question was really supposed to mean "what is the equivalent of getting data from user in C++", and not "what is the precise equivalent of scanf function in C++".

Comment: If we truly *had* to get into a lot of detail, and we were truly sure about the intent and experience level of the OP, you might be right. None of those is true though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If we aren't sure about experience level of the OP, we cannot assume, that he's advanced enough to take advantage of your comment as well, are we? Especially when he writes *explicite*: "I am the beginner in C++"

Comment: @JerryCoffin Anyway; it's your right to downvote. I still keep my opinion, that in this particular case using `std::cin` is an answer. I may however include your comment in my answer, if I'm wrong and OP is really interested in these specifics.

Comment: @JerryCoffin (like the OP was paying attention to answers at all, BTW)

Comment: He says he's a beginner in C++. That doesn't necessarily mean he's a beginner in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
    int main(){
     int i;
      cout << "enter code here: ";
      cin >> i;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout` or `using namespace std;` would be also in order

Comment: See my comment on Spook's answer--the same applies here.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `scanf("%c",&c)` is `c = cin.get();`

For writing statement, you can use `cout`, for example `cout << "enter code here";`